# Receive Event Grid from a Service Bus Handler on Azure Services

Tags: .net, azure, azureservicebus, azure-eventgrid

I am sending the event on the event grid like. i can see they arriving at the azure dashboard

```
            NomeEmailChange yay = new NomeEmailChange
            {
                Nome = "cesco",
                Email = "cesco"
            };

            var primaryTopicKey = _config["EventGridConfig:AcessKey"];
            var primaryTopic = _config["EventGridConfig:Endpoint"];

            var primaryTopicHostname = new Uri(primaryTopic).Host;

            var topicCredentials = new TopicCredentials(primaryTopicKey);
            var client = new EventGridClient(topicCredentials);

            var id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            var hey = new List<EventGridEvent>
            {
                new EventGridEvent()
                {
                    Id = id,
                    EventType = "cesco-cesco",
                    Data = (yay),
                    EventTime = DateTime.Now,
                    Subject = "MS_Clientes",
                    DataVersion = "1.0",
                }
            };
            ;
            client.PublishEventsAsync(primaryTopicHostname, hey);
```

then I created a event grid subscrition. i can confirm on the event grid messages arriving to the event grid subscription.

On another project  I am subscribing to the service bus like the bellow. it works fine for consuming messages sent directly to the bus.

```
        public static IServiceCollection AddBus(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration,
            IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            services.AddMassTransit(x => { x.AddConsumer<NomeEmailChangeConsumer>(); });
            services.AddSingleton(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(cfg =>
            {
                var keyName = "RootManageSharedAccessKey";
                var busName = configuration["ServiceBus:Name"];
                var secret = configuration["ServiceBus:Secret"];
                var host = cfg.Host(
                    "Endpoint=sb://" + busName + ".servicebus.windows.net/;" +
                    "SharedAccessKeyName=" + keyName + ";" +
                    "SharedAccessKey=" + secret,
                    z =>
                    {
                        TokenProvider
                            .CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider(keyName, secret);
                    });
                cfg.UseExtensionsLogging(provider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>());
                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, configuration["ServiceBus:Topic"],
                    e => { e.Consumer<NomeEmailChangeConsumer>(provider); });
            }));
            services.AddSingleton<IPublishEndpoint>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<IBusControl>());
            services.AddSingleton<ISendEndpointProvider>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<IBusControl>());
            services.AddSingleton<IBus>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<IBusControl>());
            services.AddScoped(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<IBus>().CreateRequestClient<NomeEmailChange>());
            services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, BusService>();
            return services;
        }
```

all supposed to work by now, but on this other project when the message arrives I get the following error

```
fail: MassTransit.Messages[0]
      R-FAULT sb://sbacompanharreldev.servicebus.windows.net/bff-queue 9ade19ec-238c-4c08-8e03-28bac695ea7b No deserializer was registered for the message content type: application/json; charset=utf-8. Supported content types include application/vnd.masstransit+json, application/vnd.masstransit+bson, application/vnd.masstransit+xml
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: No deserializer was registered for the message content type: application/json; charset=utf-8. Supported content types include application/vnd.masstransit+json, application/vnd.masstransit+bson, application/vnd.masstransit+xml
   at MassTransit.Serialization.SupportedMessageDeserializers.Deserialize(ReceiveContext receiveContext)
   at MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.DeserializeFilter.Send(ReceiveContext context, IPipe`1 next)
   at GreenPipes.Filters.RescueFilter`2.GreenPipes.IFilter<TContext>.Send(TContext context, IPipe`1 next)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59195982/11228967 - feedback would be nice, to know if it works or not for you, as decent amout of time was invested to explore this problem. Thanks :)

Comment: @kgalic
the deserializer you send me does not compile on this line 
eturn new JsonConsumeContext(JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(), receiveContext, messageEnv);

Comment: it says it need 4 arguments

Comment: Did you try to download the sample from the repository I provided and try to run it?

Comment: Also, are you using .net core or .net framework?

Comment: @kgalic .net core

Comment: I can try to run it once more but if you downloaded the repository it should work as it is based on the dotnet core. Can you please verify if you have the same package versions installed as in my example and repo?

Comment: MassTransit is an open-source project, please have a look here, and you can see that JsonConsumeContext has constructor only with 3 params: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/6e75ca3ed77af800d216dec0edc8124f1c2b4589/src/MassTransit/Serialization/JsonConsumeContext.cs

Comment: Here is another example of how to use it(also 3 params), similar like in my deserializer: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/3b98c2819fdddc519d4ad88e3873255013aa137d/src/MassTransit/Serialization/BsonMessageDeserializer.cs

I also tried to run the code, and as in my screenshot(from the answer), I am receiving the messages through my deserializer. Could you please check if you can build and run my example, with your queue/topic connection string and queue/topic name?

Answer (score 5):

As suggested you have to write the custom deserializer. In my implementation, I changed a couple of things on how to deal with the MassTransit package.

First, you have to register deserializers for different Content Types:

1. For example, if your message come from MassTransit publisher it will be the default message ContentType(in C#): `JsonMessageSerializer.JsonContentType`
2. If your message comes from the ServiceBus queue/topic, it is usually `"application/json"`

The following code shows how to register deserializers, and how to set up the receiving endpoint. One difference compared to your approach is that I used connection string, so no need for SAS token part.

```
class Program
    {
        static string ContentTypeJson = "application/json";
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(cfg =>
            {
                var queueName = "Your SB Queue Name";
                var connectionString = "Connection String with RooTManage policy";
                var host = cfg.Host(connectionString, h =>
                {
                    h.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
                });

                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(queueName,
                    e =>
                    {
                        e.AddMessageDeserializer(contentType: new ContentType(ContentTypeJson), () =>
                        {
                            return new EventGridMessgeDeserializer(ContentTypeJson);
                        });
                        e.Consumer(() => new EventGridMessageConsumer());

                        // Uncomment if required deserializer for local messages - mass transit as publisher or direct messages from SB
                        //e.AddMessageDeserializer(contentType: JsonMessageSerializer.JsonContentType, () =>
                        //{
                        //    return new CustomMessageDeserializer(JsonMessageSerializer.JsonContentType.ToString());
                        //});
                        //e.Consumer(() => new MessageConsumer());
                    });

            });
            bus.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            // for testing purposes of local messages - mass transit as publisher
            // await bus.Publish<CustomMessage>(new {  Hello = "Hello, World." });
            await Task.Run(() => Console.ReadKey());

            await bus.StopAsync();

        }
```

I used my [message simulator](https://github.com/kgalic/DeviceSimulator) to pipe the messages to the EventGrid, which forwards the messages to the SB queue, and below you can see the outcome of running this code:

[image]

Deserializer for event grid messages, as well as full code, you can find on Github: https://github.com/kgalic/MassTransitSample and also in my answer on your other question.

Answer (score 0):

MassTransit is using message envelope that is used to deserialize the content.
You will need to create and register a custom serializer to allow MassTransit ingest and process your messages. For more information, see [Interoperability](https://masstransittemp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/interop.html) documentation. Once a custom serializer is created, it can be registered using [configuration API](https://masstransittemp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/bus_configuration.html#selecting-an-outbound-message-serializer).

Comment: any example on how to do this ?

Comment: I couldn't locate any samples within the documentation. Perhaps that's worth a separate question 

Comment: And looks like you've [raised it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59107284/how-to-write-a-masstransit-json-deserializer-for-azure-services) already.

Comment: and I started a bounty there too!

Comment: @CESCO I provided an example of how to write custom deserializer for EventGrid messages, as well as the full working solution as an example. please check your other question, as well as the answer on this one which explains how to incorporate deserializer with MassTransit setup.

Comment: @CESCO did you have a chance to check out my sample? Any luck?

Comment: Sorry have not.